# How to replace a value to another value in a specific column on a gzipped file using awk?

Tags: awk, replace

I have a compressed file (.gz) The file has approx 7000000 rows and the first few lines look like this:

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  T_STAT  P
1   54712   1:54712 TTTTC   T   ADD 1460    0.00428077  0.0561095   0.0762931   0.939196
1   825069  rs4475692   G   C   G   ADD 1460    -0.000411661    0.0413083   -0.00996558 0.99205
1   825410  rs13303179  G   A   G   ADD 1460    0.00489633  0.041967    0.116671    0.907137
```

The end of the  file has X in the first column

```
X   154929637   rs35185538:154929637:CT:C   CT  C   C   ADD 1460    0.0787708   0.0396199   1.98816 0.0469823
X   154929952   rs4012982:154929952:CAA:C   CAA C   C   ADD 1460    0.0265508   0.0522027   0.50861 0.611104
X   154930230   rs781880:154930230:A:G  A   G   G   ADD 1460    0.0827871   0.0356246   2.32387 0.0202707
```

I want to replace the X (only the X) to 23 and preserve the header. I have tried to no avail.

```
gunzip -c file.gz | awk 'NR==1{gsub(/\X/,"23",$1)} 1' > out.txt
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Avni.

Comment: Being new into R is irrelevant since nothing in your question is about R, and the original file being gzipped is also irrelevant since you have to unzip it to use awk on it and zip  it again afterwards. It's best to stick to just what's relevant in your questions so it's easiest for us to see and understand your actual problem you need help with.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (not a few lines of the start of a file then a few lines of the end of a file, simply a complete small file), expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Comment: Regarding your regexp `/\X/` the letter `X` isn't a regexp metacharacter so you shouldn't escape it to try to make it literal as it is already literal. By escaping it you could undesirably turn it into a regexp metachar, e.g. `S` is the letter `S` but in some awks `\S` is a regexp shorthand for `[[:space:]]`. So don't escape any characters in a regexp unless you're sure you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check only for X in the first column and check if the row number is greater than 1.

Then you can replace X at the start of the string using `^X` with 23.

```
awk 'NR > 1 && $1=="X" {sub(/^X/,"23")}1' > out.txt
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. Can you use this command when dealing with compressed files?

Comment: @AvniKaur Do you mean like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498587/how-to-extract-information-using-awk-on-gz-files-without-storing-the-uncompress

Comment: It worked when I used the file was a text format. Can you use the awk command on a compressed file? E.g. gz file. i tried to do gunzip -c file.gz | awk command but it did  not work.

Comment: @AvniKaur I ran `gunzip -c file.gz | awk 'NR > 1 && $1=="X" {sub(/^X/,"23")}1' > out.txt` and for me it worked using the 7 example lines from the example. Did you get any error?

Comment: @AvniKaur No you can't use awk or any other **text**-processing tool on a compressed file because such a file is not **text**. See the POSIX standard for any tool you're interested in and note if it says the input must be a **text** file, as it does for awk, sed, grep, etc.. Yes you can run awk or any other text processing tool on a file that had previously been compressed as long as the resulting file is a text file - the fact that that file had been compressed is completely irrelevant, all that matters is what it IS, not where it came from.

Comment: For example see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html and look  under `INPUT FILES` where it says "Input files to the awk program from any of the following sources shall be **text** files:" (emphasis mine). POSIX also defines a text file as one that doesn't contain NUL chars and every line ends with a linefeed (`\n`).